# Split ROSbag to two

Tags: ros, filter, rosbag, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using rosindigo on two computers. I am using a ROS bag which includes sensor data from a robot (it's the Cartographer Deutsches museum 2D dataset) used to build a map.
I would like to split the bag such that I will be able to run it as if it's collected from two robots, so lets say if the bag is 2000sec long the I would like to split it to two 1000sec bags and treat it as if both halves where collected at the same time by two different robots.
Would I be able to do this using rosbag filter? If so how? Would I need to fix time-stamping in the rosbag?

I am a relatively new user so would be happy for pointers...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290143/split-rosbag-to-two/) by [ecidon](https://answers.ros.org/users/34916/ecidon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-05-01**:
Split it as in first half and second half w.r.t time?

**Comment by [ecidon](https://answers.ros.org/users/34916/ecidon/) on 2018-05-01**:
The first half time, so lets say the whole bag runs form 0-2000sec and we have a message each second I would like to have
sec 1: message 1 from first half + message 1 from second half
sec 2: message 2 from first half + message 2 from second half

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-05-01**:
See #q99711

**Comment by [robotchicken](https://answers.ros.org/users/34838/robotchicken/) on 2018-05-02**:
Since the messages have to be played simultaneously, the messages would have to be time stamped accordingly. So I am guessing #q99711 wouldn't apply.

Either way, please mark the question as resolved based on the answer that worked.

**Comment by [ecidon](https://answers.ros.org/users/34916/ecidon/) on 2018-05-02**:
Thanks, marked as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should use this solution: [How to split a recorded rosbag file ?](https://answers.ros.org/question/99711/how-to-split-a-recorded-rosbag-file/)

---

Originally posted by [Clemens](https://answers.ros.org/users/34924/clemens/) with karma: 16 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ecidon](https://answers.ros.org/users/34916/ecidon/) on 2018-05-02**:
Sorry for the late reply, this worked for my situation